# How do I locate files that appear to be located before the webroot?

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, redirects, godaddy

I'm now administering a site for a small professional organisation. The website is hosted with GoDaddy. Most of the links don't work as the site was migrated back from `https` to `http`. All of this work **predates** my involvement.

The `.htaccess` file is long and complicated with a large number of `rewritecond` and `rewriterule` code.

One of the rewrite conditions/rules is working and the others are not. The key difference appears to be that the page direction that is working is to a file that looks like it is located prior to the webroot.

The original file path takes this form:
`http://TheFileName1.example.com`

which is successfully converted to:
`http://www.example.com/TheFileName10` and shows on the website.

My limited understanding is that the webroot is where the `www.example.com` is based, so that one would expect `TheFileName10` to show inside the webroot.

I can't locate `TheFileName10`.

Is it likely that this file is stored on the same web hosting server, and why can't I see it?

I'm hoping to use this file as the basis to get the others working. But as I am unable to locate where it is, I'm stuck on fixing the other pages.

**Edited to add**, parts of the `.htaccess` file, with content anonymised. I've missed out all the code relating to the `FileName[x]` 0, 2 through 9 as it duplicates the code for `Filename1`.

Everything is stored in subfolders under `\secure` *except for* `FileName10`, which I can't locate in the folder structure.

The website was also restructured so that the pages are under the `\secure` older instead of being directly inside the webroot.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# code for website page that works
rewritecond %{http_host} ^TheFileName10\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^$ http://example.com/TheFileName10/ [r=301,L]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^AlternativeFileName10\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^$ http://example.com/TheFileName10/ [r=301,L]
# working code stops here

# code for one of the pages that don't work
rewritecond %{http_host} ^TheFileName1\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^$ http://secure.example.com/TheFileName1/ [r=301,L]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^AlternativeFileName1\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^$ http://secure.example.com/TheFileName1/ [r=301,L]
# this code isn't working stops here

# the website structure is that everything should be situated inside the secure folder
rewritecond %{http_host} ^secure\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [r=301,L]

rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?secure\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://secure.example.com/$1 [r=301,L]

rewritecond %{http_host} ^secure\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^TheFileName$ http://example.com/TheFileName10/ [nc,r=301,L]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^secure\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^TheFileName/$ http://example.com/TheFileName10/ [nc,r=301,L]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^secure\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^TheFileName/(.*)$ http://orsnz.org.nz/TheFileName50/$1 [nc,r=301,L]

rewritecond %{http_host} ^secure\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(FileName|FileName10|FileName9|FileName8|FileName7|FileName6|FileName5|FileName4|FileName3|FileName2|FileName1|FileName0)$ http://secure.example.com/$1/ [nc,r=301,L]

rewritecond %{http_host} ^secure\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^secure(.*)$ secure$1 [nc,L]

rewritecond %{http_host} ^secure\.example\.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ secure/$1 [nc,L]
```

There seems to be a lot of duplicate conditions and rules.

It is a WordPress site, and I have left out the WordPress code. The `.htaccess` is 257 lines, including white lines and comments. I am seriously out of my depth. I can read code, I have my own little WordPress site, but I am not used to an `.htaccess` file this complicated.

Comment: Where are you seeing `http://TheFileName/www.example.com`?   In that url, `TheFileName` would be interpreted as the host name, so the request would go to a server of that name.   That isn't a fully qualified domain name, so it shouldn't work.   It might work on a local network where the full domain name is automatically added: `TheFileName.example.com` which then resolves to your server somehow?    You need to give us more information so we can help you.

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller. That construction occurs in the .htaccess file. I'll paste in the parts of the relevant, but anonymised parts of the .htaccess file that appear to be relevant.

Comment: I don't actually see `http://TheFileName/www.example.com` in the *.htaccess* that you pasted in.   I do see `TheFileName1\.example\.com` which is a subdomain.  I edited your question to make the top part match the htaccess file.